# Understand the Mukai vector

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a K3 surface and $h:=c_1(i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^3}}(1))$, then we can compute that $c_1(S)=0,c_2(S)=6h^2$. Hence
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\text{td}(S)}=1+\frac{c_2(S)}{24}=1+\frac{1}{4}h^2
\end{align}
According to materials e.g. *Lectures on K3 Surfaces*, the Mukai vector of a vector bundle $E$ on $S$ is defined by
$$\nu(E):=\text{ch}(E).\sqrt{\text{td}(S)}=(\text{rk}(E),c_1(E),\text{ch}_2(E)+\text{rk}(E))$$
I am a bit confused about the operation $.$ between $\text{ch}(E)$ and $\sqrt{\text{td}(S)}$. By the appearance, I guess that it was given by
$$v_k=\sum_{i+j=k}\text{ch}_i(E)\bullet(\sqrt{\text{td}(S)})_j$$
by some operation $\bullet$. But then it turns out that $\text{rk}(E)\bullet\frac{1}{4}h^2=\text{rk}(E)$. Here I get $h=4$ and $c_2(S)=24$.

> But $h\in H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is a cohomology class, how should I understand $h=4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c_2(S)$ should not depend on the choice of polarization. See Corollary 3.3 of Huybrecht's Lectures on K3 surfaces.

$c_2(S) = 24 c_s$ where $c_s$ is the generator of $H^2(S, \mathbb{Z})$. Then note that $\sqrt{td(S)} = (1+2c_S)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + c_S$.